# Unexpected result in simple java program

Tags: java

I am new to java and my problem is that the output is showing 2 numbers after I press a key and I can't understand why.

This is the code:

```
class ForTest {    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        int i;
        System.out.println("Press S to stop.");
        for(i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 'S'; i++)
            System.out.println("Pass #" + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which key do you press? What does `System.in.read()` do?

Comment: I guess that is `int java.io.InputStream.read()` ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://ideone.com/kreQX2 Are you hitting a key and then enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I cannot reproduce the issue: ([See Here](http://ideone.com/kreQX2)), my suggestion is to print out the character (as an integer) as well. This will help you debug:

```
for(i = 0; (char)( int c = System.in.read() ) != 'S'; i++)
   System.out.println("Pass #" + i + ": " + c);
```

Comment: Thanks... I think i found out the problem... its getting another input whose ascii value is 10. I think its the enter key. thats how its getting two inputs.

Comment: @Karthik.Venkata That's the ASCII code for newline, see my answer for an actual explanation. It's because Java uses buffered I/O when reading from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling that your problem is with buffered I/O. I'm assuming between your "key presses" you're hitting enter? On most systems I/O doesn't flush until input receives a newline. The problem with this is that the buffer then has a newline in it which counts towards the character count in your loop.

Edit:

If this is indeed the case, it seems like you want your "passes" to be the number of lines before you hit a line comprising only of "S." If so, try using something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class ForTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int i;
        System.out.println("Press S to stop.");
        for(i = 0; !br.readLine().equals("S"); i++)
            System.out.println("Pass #" + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your program and I think I see the problem, if you look closely, you'll see that when you do two key presses you have 3 output, when you do three key presses you have 4 output etc.
The problem is that `System.in.read()` does count a newline as a character so you'll always have one more output.

Answer (score 1):

See the description of read method in Input stream . Internally it makes 2 calls. If the first call results in IOException, it will again make another call which if returns IOException.. then it would be treated as End of file.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html