# Simple For loop - executes too many times IMO

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm working through a piece of code from the "Java: A Beginner's Guide 6th Ed." The section I'm on is explaining the different ways to implement a For Loop.

```
// Loop until an S is typed. 

System.out.println("Press S to stop."); 

for(int i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 'S'; i++) 
    System.out.println("Pass #" + i);
```

My question is this - why does it execute 3 times before asking for a new keyboard input? When I type any character, it outputs:

```
Press S to stop.

T

Pass #0

Pass #1

Pass #2

P

Pass #3

Pass #4

Pass #5
```

I would expect it to run once and then wait for the next input.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22922567/2777098

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm sure you didn't just press 'T' and 'P'. 
You pressed 'T' <kbd>return</kbd> 'P' <kbd>return</kbd>. 
And a <kbd>return</kbd> on the Windows platform is represented by two characters: carriage return (`\r`) followed by a line feed (`\n`).

So by typing 'T' <kbd>return</kbd> you typed 3 characters:

1. 'T'
2. `\r`
3. `\n`

That's why.

It's not a Java thing. Exactly the same thing would have happened if you had written your program in C or Perl.

If you are just using `System.in`, then it's not possible to get individual keypresses on most consoles - instead you won't get any data until the <kbd>return</kbd> has been pressed. You can write a GUI application instead of you want to have more detailed insight into key presses.

Comment: Thank you Erwin for quickly responding with such a thorough, insightful explanation!

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, the extra iterations represent the `EOL` or *End of Line* characters. When you type a character as input, you need to type an additional character to deliver the standard input for your program: probably the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

To see this more clearly, here's a simple amendment to your code:

```
// Loop until an S is typed. 

System.out.println("Press S to stop."); 

char read;

for (int i = 0; (read = (char) System.in.read()) != 'S'; i++) 
{
    System.out.print("Pass #" + i); 

    // specific checks for LF \n, or CR \r

    if (read == '\n')
        System.out.println("; char read was: \\n");
    else if (read == '\r')
        System.out.println("; char read was: \\r");
    else System.out.println("; char read was: " + read);
}
```

Output:

```
Press S to stop.
T
Pass #0; char read was: T
Pass #1; char read was: \r
Pass #2; char read was: \n
P
Pass #3; char read was: P
Pass #4; char read was: \r
Pass #5; char read was: \n
S
```

From my output, and from yours, we can make a good guess that the system that we're running this loop on is a Wndows-based system. Note that different operating systems have represented this character differently: so you should expect to see different output when you run your code on a UN*X based system, like on a mac. See [the wikipedia article for Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) for more information.

The java language makes a useful abstraction for this that you can use in more complex code: the standard library captures the operating-system dependent value for `EOL` in `System.lineSeparator`, see the docs for `lineSeparator` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator())

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to make it work as you were expecting, you could use a scanner like so:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press S to stop."); 

    for(int i = 0; scanner.next().charAt(0) != 'S'; i++) 
        System.out.println("Pass #" + i);
```

That gives the following output:

```
Press S to stop.
W
Pass #0
R
Pass #1
T
Pass #2
S
```

Comment: I'll have to research the scanner function more deeply. Thanks for sharing, swingMan!